# Как сделать чтобы dropdown окно было открыто даже при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Есть код dropdown окна, который работает, но при переходе на другую страничку он закрывается. Что в принципе и логично. Я попробовал некоторый обход, но это не помогло. Вот код

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left_block">
        <div class="box" id="menu">
            <div class="title">
                Список №1
                <span class="expand">+</span>
            </div>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li class="test" ><a asp-controller="Article" asp-action="GetArticle" asp-route-id=1>Article 1</a></li>
                <li class="test"><a asp-controller="Article" asp-action="GetArticle" asp-route-id=2>Article 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_block">
        <div class="maincontent">
            @{
                if (Model != null)
                {
                    @Html.Raw(Model[0]);

                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            $(".dropdown").show();
                        });
                    </script>

                    <div class="text-center"><input type="submit" value="Попробовать Пример" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(Model[1], "api")'" /></div>
                    <p></p>
                }

            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dropdown").hide();
        $(".box div").click(function () {
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
            var text = $("span", this).text();
            $("span", this).text(text != "+" ? "+" : "-")
        });
    });
</script>
```

При нажатии на ссылку открывается та же страница но уже с текстом и другим URN. А именно Article/GetArticle/1 . URN первоначальной страницы: Article/Section . Как я уже говорил закрывается dropdown. В maincontent я попробовал кое что, вдруг поможет, но ничего не изменилось. Что было ожидаемо, но я все же понадеялся) На других сайтах я видел что такое возможно. А конкретно в vk dev в разделе документации. Там когда выбираю другие dropdown поля они не закрываются.

Comment: можно закинуть в sessionStorage переменную с значением, записывать и читать значение оттуда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обработчики `$(document).ready` выполняются в порядке регистрации.

```
    <script>
      //$(document).ready(function () {
      //    $(".dropdown").show();
      //});
    </script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
@if (Model != null) {
        $(".dropdown").show();
} else {
        $(".dropdown").hide();
}
        ...
```